# The "slot" component is not displayed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I try to build a dynamic component with `slot`. To do that, I have this `layout`:

```
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            LAYOUT NOT CONNECTED    
            <slot />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

In which there is the `<slot>`.

I have this component `login`:

```
<template>
    <div>bla bla</div>
</template>
```

My app is:

```
<template>
    <component :is="layout">
        <router-view />
    </component>
</template>
    
<script>
const default_layout = 'layout-not-connected'
    
export default {
    computed: {
        layout() {
            console.log(this.$route.meta.layout || default_layout)
            return (this.$route.meta.layout || default_layout)
        }
    },
...
```

And at my route is:

```
{
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    meta: { layout : 'layout-not-connected' },
    component: Login
},
```

The result is that only `LAYOUT NOT DISPLAYED` is displayed and not the login component.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: if you added something else besides `<router-view />` it appears??

Comment: yes : if I add something else besides <router-view> it appears near the sentence "LAYOUT NOT DISPLAYED"

Comment: The problem is with your `<router-view />` check my answer to get a hint

Comment: A now-deleted answer was given that pointed [to this resource](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2020/02/24/extending-vuejs-components-templates/).

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

Try to use a [named-routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html#nested-named-views):

```
<template>
    <component :is="layout">
        <router-view name="a" />
    </component>
</template>
```

while router instance:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      components: {
        default: Foo,
        a: Bar,
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

### Solution 2

Keep the actual router-view and make sure you have the matched route object in the `routes` array

```
<template>
    <component :is="layout">
        <router-view />
    </component>
</template>
```

And router instance:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    // dynamic segments start with a colon
    { path: '/user/:id', component: User }
  ]
})
```